# phpでクライアント証明書の認証

Tags: php, nginx, ssl

nginxで行っているクライアント証明書(pfx)の認証を
サーバ上のphpで実装することを検討しております。

1.クライアント証明書の内容がどこに格納されているか教えていただけないでしょうか。
2.以下のチェックをphpで行いたいのですが、実装方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

■チェック内容
・有効期限
・サブジェクト
・発行者
・拇印

Answer (score 1):

変数 http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables に入っているので、例えば、`fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_I_DN $ssl_client_i_dn;` で渡せば、PHP 側で `$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_I_DN']` で取り出せると思います。

Comment: 詳細なサイトの提示、実装例、ありがとうございました。
こちらの方法で実装したいと思います。